# jquery only selected row values get pass to another page for map view

Tags: jquery, dictionary

- in my proj  map table records with location name,lat,long,map view(static link clik to redirect map page).
- this is my jquery code for table creation

  ```
    var oTable = $('#tblMAP').dataTable( {
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "bPaginate": false,
     "aaData": [],
     "asStripeClasses": [ 'strip1', 'strip1'],
     "bAutoWidth": false,
     "aoColumns": [
     { "sTitle": "Location Name", "sClass": "text-left", "sWidth": "30%" }, //forom DB
     { "sTitle": "Lat", "sClass": "text-left", "sWidth": "30%" }, // from DB
     { "sTitle": "Long", "sClass": "text-left", "sWidth": "30%" }, // FROM DB
     { "sTitle": "MAP VIEW", "sClass": "text-left", "sWidth": "10%" } // how to give link to another page
     ]
     } );
  ```

  - and my java script code is

    `var obj = { itemParent: "Record", itemNames: ["name","LT","LN"] };
    var aaData = $.paramquery.xmlToArray( $.parseXML( response ), obj);
    var oTable = $('#tblMAP').dataTable();
    oTable.fnClearTable();
    $('#tblMAP').dataTable().fnAddData(aaData);
    window.setTimeout(function(){$('#tblMAP').dataTable().fnFilter('');},500);
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').niceScroll();
    if(aaData.length == 0) showMessagePopUpBox("Data not available");
    $('#tblMAP tr').click(function() {
        $('#tblMAP tr').removeClass('ui-state-highlight')
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData();
        getmappage(); // redirect to another page
                   (or)
                   $('#mapview').show();
    $('#mapview').load('../map/getmappage.html');
    } );`
  - how to to get that only selected values in new page.
  - i tried like this..

    `function initializea() {
    $('#map-canvass').css("height",(window.innerHeight-150)+"px");
    $('#map-canvass').css("width","100%");
    oTableExt = $('#tbleMAP').dataTable();
    tablerows=$('#tblMAP tr').size(); // here getting correct rows
    if($('# tbleMAP tr.ui-state-highlight').is(':selected')){
    alert("selected")
    }else{
    alert("UN-selected")
    }// here i get UN-Selected
    var mapOptions = {
    center:  myLatLng,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map-canvass');
    .............`
  - please help for sample code, and how to give "MAP VIEW" option in table by static link(not entire row).

    - that selected row lat,long values get another map page.
    - please save my days

Comment: if($('# tbleMAP tr.ui-state-highlight').is(':selected')) its not giving record of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- simple try this one

`$('# tbleMAP tr.ui-state-highlight').each(function(){
// your logic using data and positions i.e, data[0][0]......
});`